# scroll the bottom of page or result if possible

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

After submit, If the page is too large, the user has to scroll down to see the results given from foo.php, I want it force the browser to scroll down to that result message, if that's possible. I'm pretty much willing to do anything to get the page to scroll down automatically, doesn't need to be using ajax. etc.

```
$(function(){
        $('button[type=submit]').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "foo.php",
                data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#result').html('<div class="success"><img src="../images/loading-blue.gif" width="25" /></div>');
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    //var objDiv = document.getElementById("#result");
                    //objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight; 
                    //(example I found online, didn't work)
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, this should be your ticket.

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
```

Comment: I found this also, would this work
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop:$('form').offset().bottom}, 'slow');

Comment: Give it a shot! Thats the fun of programming, try/catch :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `javascript`. Where `result` is the `id` of the result `div`

```
document.getElementById('result').scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("body").animate({scrollTop:$("#result").offset().top},500);`

This will scroll right at `$("#result")`.

For a better response you should also give us the CSS of `#result`, cause we don't know it's position (absolute, fixed, static, relative)

Answer (score 0):

If result is indeed the last element on the page, an improvement to Rottingham's answer would be to do this:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()-$(window).height(), "slow");
```

This is better because the time specified in the second parameter should be the time that it takes for your window to reach the end of the page, whereas with Rottingham's answer, it would move down a little too fast.

Comment: @AlbertD That is just your personal preference. That does not change the fact that the document scrolls to the bottom before the 600ms specified for the "slow" keyword.